# Drupal commerce - page titles from product name

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-commerce

I've installed a drupal commerce module. And I made an article with some products.
So I want to change the page title to the title of selected from list product in this article. I tried to use Page_title module, but there is no token I need.

Screenshot: http://s7.postimage.org/3svsccp0b/file.jpg

Comment: Is the Entity Tokens module enabled on your site?

Comment: yeap. I found the token needed. But there is new problem. I'm using [node:field-myproduct:title], it shows me all titles of my product in page title. but I need only 1 product. any ideas?

Comment: Its usually something like `[node:field-myproduct:title:0]` or `[node:field-myproduct:title:0:value]` where the zero is the item index

Comment: the zero index is working, but it only shows the 1st(if i use 1 or 2 it'll show me the 2nd or the 3rd product title) value doesn't work.